# Render Django @property method in html template

Tags: django, django-models

I am relatively new to django. I am trying to render my @property method inside my django template. I am taking the difference between two dads to determine wether or not this object is suitable to be issued out or must recalibrated.

I get an issue: `'int' object is not callable`

My model:

```py
class Tools_Calibrated(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    recieved = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    calibrated = models.BooleanField(default='True', blank=True, null=True)
    calibrated_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    cert_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    range_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    issued = models.BooleanField(default='False', blank=True, null=True)
    workorder_no = models.ForeignKey(
        WorkOrders, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    @property
    def timecalculated(self):
        exp = self.expiry_date
        cali = self.calibrated_date
        total = exp-cali
        return total.days()
```

My Template:

```
      {% for tool in Cali %}
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.description}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.part_number}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.serial_number}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.recieved|date:"M d, Y"}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.calibrated_date|date:"M d, Y"}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.expiry_date|date:"M d, Y"}}</td>
                        <td>{{tool.timecalculated}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.cert_no}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center">{{tool.range_no}}</td>

                        <td style="text-align:center"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info sb-btn" href="{% url 'editCali' tool.id%}">Edit</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger sb-btn" onClick='return confirmDelete()' href="{% url 'deleteCali' tool.id %}">Delete</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning sb-btn" href="{% url 'change_calibration_status' tool.id%}" onClick='return confirmCali()'>Calibrate</a></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary sb-btn" href="{% url 'issueworkorderCali' tool.id%}">Issue to W/O</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the (): `return total.days`

`days` itself is a property, and doesn't need to be called.